# Cannonical Correlation Analysis

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation

I have just started working using CCA in Matlab. I have two vectors `X` and `Y` of dimension `60x1920` and `60x1536` with the number of samples being `60` and variables in the different set of vectors being `1920` and `1536` respectively. I want to know do CCA for reducing them to the subspace and then do feature matching.

I am using this commands.

```
%% DO CCA
[A,B,r,U,V] = canoncorr(X,Y);
```

The output I get is this :

```
  Name         Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         1920x58            890880  double              
  B         1536x58            712704  double              
  U           60x58             27840  double              
  V           60x58             27840  double              
  r            1x58               464  double
```

Can anyone please tell me what these variables mean. I have gone over the  documentation several times and still is unclear about them. As I understand CCA finds two linear projection matrices `Wx` and `Wy` such that the projection of `X` and `Y` on `Wx` and `Wy` are maximally correlated.

1) Could anyone please tell me which of the following matrices are these?

2) Also how can I find the projected vectors in the learned subspace of CCA?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/canoncorr.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I really did look at the documentation but still had some doubts. Could you please tell me which are the projection vectors? I think it is A and B and the projections on the CCA subspace is U and V. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, with `X` and `Y` being your original data matrices, `A` and `B` are the sets of coefficients that perform a change of basis to maximally correlate your original data. Your data is represented in the new bases as the matrices `U` and `V`.

So to answer your questions:

1. The projection matrices you are looking for would be `A` and `B` since they transform `X` and `Y` into the new space.
2. The resulting projections of `X` and `Y` into the new space would be `U` and `V`, respectively. (The `r` vector represents the entries of the correlation matrix between `U` and `V`, which is a diagonal matrix.)

The The [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/canoncorr.html) says this transformation can be done with the following formulae, where `N` is the number of observations:

```
U = (X-repmat(mean(X),N,1))*A
V = (Y-repmat(mean(Y),N,1))*B
```

[This page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/65) lays out the process nicely so you can see what each coefficient means in the transformation process.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you help me a bit further. I am actually trying to design a basic face recognition program. In this I get the vectors X and Y which are actually face images from two different modalities. Then I do subspace learning by CCA to convert them into a common subspace. Now suppose I get an image query and I want to label it. I am supposed to find the class to which it has maximum similarity. So I will use either of the U or  V matrices to convert them into the common subspace. But then how can I compare this to U and V matrices? Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think CCA actually finds a common subspace. Rather, it finds *two* individual subspaces that represent your two sets of data more conveniently so that the correlations between the two sets of data become more obvious. You might find this answer useful to read: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133496/how-does-cca-find-a-low-dimensional-common-subspace
I'm afraid I don't have enough experience to help you further. Cross-Validated is a better forum for getting help with statistics and machine learning problems.