# using Canonical Correlation Analysis in MATLAB for Image retrieval?

Tags: matlab

we have 300 train images and one test image. After calculating **"Bag of visual words"**, we get a `big histogram matrix` for train images (250 row and 300 columns) and a `small histogram matrix` for test image (250 row and 1 column).

> **Now:**
>
> How to use [Canonical Correlation Analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/canoncorr.html?refresh=true) to find 5 nearest columns
>   in big histogram matrix?

Comment: Show some code. I will help coz I am presently working in cca

Comment: Are you sure you need cca to do this ? The thing is cca is useful for comparing data of two different modality. Hence during training stage you need 300 images from both the modalities to get the projection vectors. On learning the projection vectors u need to project your probe and galley data-set for comparison.

Comment: Though these questions have yet not been answered check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168362/computing-cca-through-three-approaches, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234644/making-sense-of-cca-matlab-implementation-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149199/cannonical-correlation-analysis